# Javascript array with custom variable indexing

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Is it possible to set the custom index of an array with a variable.

for example:

```
var indexID = 5;
var temp = {
    indexID: new Array()
};
```

The above example sets the array index to `indexID` and not `5`. I have tried using `=` snd quotes but I without any success.

Thnaks

Comment: Just for clearity. **`temp` is not an array.**

Comment: This is still not working. This works: var temp = {5:new Array()}; - but if I substitute the 5 for a variable it falls over. I have tried all suggested solutions...

Comment: Ok yes I see I am confusing arrays and objects. Put another way, what I am trying to do is create an array which has as it's first numeric index a value other than 0. So the first index in my case would be 5.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, just use square brackets notation:

```
var temp = {};
temp[indexID] = [];
```

Also pay attention to the fact that `temp` is an object, and not an array. In JavaScript all *associative arrays* (or *dictionaries*) are represented as objects.

**MORE:** http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html#vId

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers. I think what I was trying to do was not best practice so I have changed my approach and used 0 as the first index of the array. I was trying to double the index of the array as variable which in hindsight isn't practical.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want is:

```
var indexID = 5;
var temp = {};
temp[indexID] = "stuff"
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you will create an object.

Instead you can do

```
var indexID = 5;
var temp = [];
temp[indexID] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `Array` with `Object`. Arrays know a (numeric) index, Objects consist of key-value pairs, where key may be any string.

Not everyone would agree, bu you could extend `Object.prototype`

```
Object.prototype.append = function(key,val){
  // confine to Object instances
  if (this.constructor !== Object && 
      !/object/i.test(this.constructor.prototype)) { return this; }
  this[key] = val;
  return this;
}
```

And subsequently use:

```
var temp = {}.append(indexID,[]};
```

Answer (score 0):

for node-red project i had to add Apostrophe to the index name

```
var Trend_1={};

Trend_1[**'x'**]=Date_TimeArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index=7;  //YOUR CUSTOM INDEX
var newarray=[];
```

If you need array index to be an array you can do it like this:

```
newarray[index] = {
                   'KEY':'VAL',
                   'KEY':'VAL',
                   'KEY':'VAL'
                    }
```

If you need to assign just a value to your custom array index you can do it like this:

```
newarray[index] = "ANY-THING-YOU-WANT"
```