# Javascript - Use Variable as Array Index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to use a variable as an array index. Variable `addThirteen` simply takes `i` and adds 13 to it. I need to use that result as the array index. Please see my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length; i ++) {
  var addThirteen = (parseInt(i) + parseInt(13));
  var newCipher = new cipher(alphabetArr[i].letter, alphabetArr[addThirteen].letter);
}
```

This results in:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'alphabetArr[addThirteen].letter')

Appreciate any help.

Comment: sounds like you are going passed the array index? are you doing a Caesar cipher?

Comment: What is the alphabetArr value?

Comment: do `var addThirteen = (i + 13) % alphabetArr.length`;

Comment: Why `parseInt(13)`? And why `parseInt(i)`? `i` is initialized with `0` (a number) and then incremented. It is always a number.

Comment: The problem is not that you're not using the variable as index, the problem is that the index doesn't exist.

Comment: I am doing a Caesar cipher. I used parseInt because i + 13 was just adding the strings together, resulting in "013". Looks like I haven't accounted for the array reaching anything after Z.

Comment: Since neither `0` nor `13` is a string, that's… weird.

Comment: pleaese refer thsi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646690/javascript-array-with-custom-variable-indexing

Comment: please refers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646690/javascript-array-with-custom-variable-indexing?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

Try printing out the iteration the for loop is on each time:

`console.log(i);
 console.log(addThirteen);`

What seems to be happening here is that when i is alphabetArr.length-13 it is trying to get a character that is outside the array. As it can't do this it throws up the error saying that the letter is undefined, because it is. A solution to this problem is:

`for (var i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length - 13; i ++) {`

Answer (score 1):

The result you are getting is really depending on what is the `alphabetArr` variable.

- The following is an example where `alphabetArr` is just an array of strings.

```js
const alphabetArr = "abcdefghejklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');

/* If you want to see what alphabetArr really is, uncomment
 * the following line an run. (copy snippet to answer to do it)
 * The result will be ["a", "b", "c", ..., "z"].
 */
// console.log(alphabetArr);

/* we will always get undefined here because alphabet[i]
 * is not an object having the property letter.
 * Instead, it is just a string.
 */
for (var i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length; i++) {
  console.log(alphabetArr[i].letter);
}
```

This example gives only `undefined` because of `alphabetArr[i]` not being an object whith the property `letter` but being a string.

- Now we will try to see what happens if `alphabetArr` is an array of objects each having the property `letter`

```js
const alphabetArr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('')
  .map(letter => ({letter: letter}));
  
// console.log(alphabetArr);
// result: [ { letter: "a" } , ... , { letter: "z" } ]

/* Here everything works fine until we reach
 * the index 13, where the output is m z
 */
for (var i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length; i++) {
  // Note that I am not parsing. It's because it is not necessary.
  var addThirteen = i + 13;
  console.log(alphabetArr[i].letter, alphabetArr[addThirteen].letter);
}
```

As you see, now we get something, but still, at a certain point, we get the thrown error. This is because the `for` loop is looping over the entire array.
So when `i` is 14, `addThirteen` will be 27. But the length of the array is 26, so `alphabetArr[27]` is `undefined`.

- Now that we understood the problem, let us solve it.

```js
const alphabetArr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('')
  .map(letter => ({letter: letter}));

for (var i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length - 13; i++) {
  // let's skip the addThirteen variable declaration.
  console.log(alphabetArr[i].letter, alphabetArr[i + 13].letter);
}
```

*Yes!* The solution is to loop over the array minus thirteen, to avoid out of range indexes.

**The final code:**

```
const alphabetArr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('')
  .map(letter => ({letter: letter}));

for (var i = 0; i < alphabetArr.length - 13; i++) {
  var newCipher = new cipher(alphabetArr[i].letter, alphabetArr[i + 13].letter);
}
```